# How to avoid if-else statements in this scenario

Tags: java, if-statement, enums

I have a class Grades who has the following body:

```
public class Grades {

    public static Grade getGrades(int marks) {
        if (marks < 10) {
            return Grade.FAILED;
        } else if (marks < 13) {
            return Grade.DISTINCTION;
        } else if (marks < 15) {
            return Grade.GREAT;
        } else {
            return Grade.GREATEST;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(getGrades(6));
    }
}
```

And a enum class:

```
public enum Grade {

    FAILED("F"),
    DISTINCTION("D"),
    GREAT("G"),
    GREATEST("G");


    private String code;

    Grade(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

}
```

How could I avoid the if else construction when calling `getGrades(int marks)`?

Comment: Why you want to avoid it? It looks good.

Comment: Pass a range of grades as additional parameters to the ctor of `Grade` (e.g. `FAILED("F", Integer.MIN_VALUE, 9), DISTINCTION("D", 10, 12)` etc, and then loop over `Grade.values()` to find an instance with a grade range containing your value.

Comment: There are a couple of answers here below: note that both of them use conditionals internally. You need if/else to do this, it's just a question of where that is located. Neither of the approaches are *really* better than your current `getGrades` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would implement a decision table for this. It will be simply a mapping between a `Predicate` (a function that takes an input and returns `true` or `false`) and a corresponding result if the `Predicate` is evaluated to `true`.

Note that Java8 introduces the [`Predicate<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) interface, which could be very helpful in your case. In addition, it could be represented as a lambda, which will reduce the verbosity of the code.

So you'd have:

```
Map<Predicate<Integer>, Grade> table = new LinkedHashMap<Predicate<Integer>, Grade>() {{
      put (x -> x < 10, Grade.FAILED);
      put (x -> x < 13, Grade.DISTINCTION);
      put (x -> x < 15, Grade.GREAT);
}};
```

Then, just iterating the decision table and to evaluating the `Predicate`s until finding such that's evaluated to `true`, should give you the answer:

```
for (Entry<Predicate<Integer>, Grade> entry : table.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().test(marks)) {
        return entry.getValue();
    }
}
return Grade.GREATEST;
```